# Error when getting an object from DataSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am implementing a database with Firebase for an android application.

I present 2 beans : `User.class` and `Address.class`, using by the app :

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {

    @Exclude
    private String idAccount;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String pseudo;
    private Address address;
    private List<Qualification> qualification;
    private boolean isWorker;

    // Constructors + getters + setters

}
```

and

```
public class Address {

    private String houseNumber;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String zip;
    private String country;

    // Constructors + getters + setters

}
```

So, I can add an user in the database with `usersRef.child(idUser).setValue(user)`, where `usersRef` is my reference of the users in the database ([See result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP6td.png))

I can also get the user with a `ValueEventListener`:

```
        Query query = usersRef.child(idUser);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                result.call(user);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });
```

([See result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppMjv.png))

So, for now all is working !

But, if I try to put a `ChildEventListener` on my `usersRef`, I have a crash :

```
 usersRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class); // crash here
                }
            }

            ...

}
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: PID: 29470
>                                                                        com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object
>   of type java.lang.String to type ca.uqac.sosdoit.data.Address
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeas.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at
>   ca.uqac.sosdoit.database.DatabaseManager$1.onChildAdded(DatabaseManager.java:68)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdri.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwu.zzbvb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxa.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
>                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

And I absolutely don't know why

Comment: Try to debug using `Map<String, String> valueMap = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();` and find the address node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like one(or some) of the User nodes has an address field of type String. Surround it with try catch and log both the exception and key of the node to find the culprit(s).

```
 usersRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
         public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

           try{
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            }
            catch(DatabaseException e){
                //Log the exception and the key 
                dataSnapshot.getKey();
            }
         }

            ...

}
```

Comment: Yes that's it! For some reason an old node has a string as address :/
Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

The error relates to Firebase trying to marshal the `address` value under one of the `user` nodes into an `Address` class instance.

The `address` value in the database should match your class `Address`, but one of them is a string which can't be converted to an `Address` instance.

If the `address` value is supposed to be a string, you'll need to change the type of the `address` field on the `User` class to `String`:

```
private String address;
```

Otherwise, you'll need to check each node under `user` in your database for any that incorrectly have a string for the `address` value.